# Sequence of the tense and its sense: "It just said..."

Tags: meaning, tenses, verb-agreement

I happen to read the following conversation in Raymond Murphy's Grammar book.

> Ann: It just said on the Radio that it is going to snow
>
> Bill: Oh!, did it?

I would like to change Ann's sentence into different ways to know whether they are right or wrong.
Besides, I feel that since the main clause is in the simple past, the sub-ordinate clause should be in the past. I know that there are some exceptions to this rule. I think 'just' in the sentence can be used in different tense and voice.

My sentences are:

1. It has just said on the Radio that it is going to rain.
2. It has just been said on that Radio that it is going to rain.
3. It was just said on the Radio that it was going to rain.
4. It just said on the Radio that it was going to rain.

I would be most grateful to you if you could enlighten me on the subject.

Comment: No. 2 is OK. No. 1 would be OK if you changed "has" to "was." 3 and 4 don't work. Also, "The radio just said it is going to rain" would be OK. Radio does not need to be capitalized.

Comment: Mr MarkHubbard' I would be more grateful to you if you explain why the other sentences do not work.comments and answers from other scholars are also welcome.

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao: You've made things difficult by choosing an unusual example context. You seem to be interested in the ***verb*** choice between Simple Past and Present Perfect, but your examples involve the particularly "strange" (to non-native speakers) idiomatic use of ***it*** as the subject. Or perhaps I should say ***subjects***, since the first instance effectively refers to ***they** (the people broadcasting on the radio)*, whereas the second one is a true "existential **it**", effectively referring to ***everything / the weather / the whole environment***.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Fumble.I hope you will talk about the grammaticality of the sentences above

Comment: @MarkHubbard I think 4. is OK, the speaker is referring to what they heard on the radio at some point in the past, e.g. ...the radio forecast *only* said it was going to rain but instead it didn't rain.

Comment: I cannot think of a single logical reason why _it_ should work as a subject (referring to the ‘they’ speaking on the radio) in the simple past, but not in the present perfect – and yet that’s how it is. “It just said it’s going to rain” is fine, but “It’s just said it’s going to rain” doesn’t work at all. I can’t think of ***any*** example where “it has just said” works in this sense, whereas “they have just said on the radio that…” is perfectly fine and natural. How utterly bizarre.

Comment: when it just said is correct, it has just said may be correct

Comment: Because you are the author of the post, every comment posted beneath will send a notification to your inbox. But if you want to address your comment to one user then you must use the @ followed by the username, for example @FumbleFingers. As soon as you type the first letter, the system will automatically supply those usernames whose names begin with that letter. One more thing, you cannot communicate directly with a user who has not posted a comment under your post. I hope this explanation helps make  your time more enjoyable and  fruitful.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it seems that you appreciated this question, could you please post an answer that includes your comment. However, if you are short on time please cast a vote to keep this question open. Thank you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: *You rang, milady?* :) I found a handful of written examples of [***it is said that it's {whatever}***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+is+said+that+it%27s%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-8-vm8uvjAhX2SxUIHdykApsQpwUIIg&biw=1559&bih=900&dpr=1) in Google Books, where the two different instances of ***it*** refer to "different" things (though it's usually not that clear *exactly* what "it" refers to in such constructions). Personally, I think it's an "awkward" usage, made even worse by pointless recasting into passive voice.